# github actions flutter gives error 'Artifact pattern :build/app/outputs/apk/release/*.apk did not match any files'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, github-actions, cicd

I created GitHub actions to run to build apk on macOS. but it gives me warning that Artifact pattern :build/app/outputs/apk/release/*.apk did not match any files.
This is a public repo, can someone please help me here. in official docs it says the same path and locally i can build apk successfully (on windows machine).
I used MacOS to generate iOs App which i'll do later.

Link of repo.
[magento-mobile-oss](https://github.com/upendra-bajpai/magento-mobile-oss)

workflow-

```
name: Magento Mobile

on:
  push:
    branches: [ oss ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ oss ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '12.x'
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          channel: stable
        env:
          KEY_JKS: ${{ secrets.KEY_JKS }}
          KEY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.ALIAS_PASSWORD }}
          ALIAS_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }}
          run: echo $KEY_JKS > key.jks && flutter pub get && flutter test &&  flutter build apk --split-per-abi --verbose
      - name: Create a Release APK
        uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
        with:
          artifacts: "build/app/outputs/apk/release/*.apk"
          token: ${{ secrets.OSS_TOKEN }}
          commit: oss
          tag: v1.0.${{ github.run_number }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow doesn't build the APK, and therefore, there's no `build/app/outputs/apk/release/*.apk` file. So the release action doesn't find the location of the *artifacts*. Here is the workflow you can use to modify yours and tweak it as you wish:

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: Build Flutter APK

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "develop" branch
  push:
    branches: ["develop"]
    tags:
      - "v*"

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: "12.x"
      - name: Setup Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          channel: "beta"

      - name: Decode android/neumodore_key.jks
        run: echo "${{ secrets.KEYSTORE_JKS_PROD }}" | base64 --decode > android/keystore.jks

      - name: Decode android/key.properties
        run: echo "${{ secrets.KEY_PROPERTIES_PROD }}" | base64 --decode > android/key.properties

      - name: Pub Get Packages
        run: flutter pub get

      - name: Build APK
        run: flutter build apk 

      - name: Create Release
        uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1.10.0
        with:
          artifacts: "build/app/outputs/apk/release/*.apk"
```